# Using a VPS to access geoblocked websites

Tags: vps

I live in Australia and want to access some US sites that geoblock Australia and also block VPNs. Can I use a Windows VPS located in Los Angeles and open a browser on that "virtual computer" to access these sites? Some VPS sites say I can get a dedicated static IP address. Does this mean that sites that I log into while using the VPS will view me the same as if I were accessing from a physical computer in Los Angeles?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work.  The IP of the VPS is what will be passed to the websites.  They will see it is in Los Angeles and you will be able to bypass any restrictions.   You dont need a dedicated IP address though.  Generally, the pools of IP addresses are all local.

That being said, performance will suffer as there will be a decent amount of latency between you and LA.  That, coupled with a remote viewing session might introduce even more latency if you are trying to stream video or even audio.  If you are just viewing static websites, you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I want a dedicated IP address is because websites I use sometimes ban mutliaccount users based on people with the same IP address. Say for example certain sports betting or day trading websites. I just want to be extra safe. The websites could not detect I was using a VPS right? I know they can detect VPNs and proxies sometimes.

Comment: @SteveB Its possible as they can see a lot if info about what is connecting.  You *could* hide that.  However, most geoblocked sites arent going to go that far.

Comment: Say I did want to hide that. Any idea where I could hire someone to help me? I'm not the most tech savvy person =/

Comment: @SteveB In theory this wouldn't be difficult, but many sites have TOS restrictions on tricks like this. And if you are banned on one IP they don't want you to return on another IP. I can give you an email address if you want. But it is unlikely you'll get help if it is super unethical/illegal.

Comment: @Gantendo thanks yes I'll take the email address. I would not categorize what I'm trying to do as illegal or super unethical